# How to determine which cells in a merged range are visible and can have a value?

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I need to find out which `Cells` of a `Range` are not visible in ranges which are merged. I need to include empty cells but I want to exclude cells that are not visible as a result of merging cells. (Only one cell, row, column in a merged range can contain a non empty value...?).

I have a following code:

```
    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook(ExcelFile.FullName))
    {
        foreach (IXLNamedRange r in wb.NamedRanges)
        {
                foreach (var c in r.Ranges.Cells())
                {
                    if (c.IsMerged() /*&& something*/)
                        continue;
                    /*Do processing of visible values*/
```

I need to get visible cells from merged ranges that would contain values if the value is filled in, i.e. without using `IsEmpty()`. I can determine, if the range is merged, but how can I add a condition to include only visible cells? Is it always the first column/row? `IsMerged()` returns `true` on all cells in a merged range not only on those that are not visible and cannot contain a value.

Example problem:

[image: Merged ranges]

A named range has the address C21:D33.
I need values of C21:C33 but I do not need to include values D21:D33 - they are all always null. But the values of C21:C33 can also be null or empty, but I need them all. D21:D33 cannot contain anything else but null, but C21:C33 can contain a non null value. I need all the cells that can be non empty.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand exactly what you want to do. `cells that are not visible as a result of merging cells`. This doesn't quite make sense to me. Merging doesn't change the visibility of cells. Hiding columns or rows change the visibility of cells in the context of `ClosedXML`. Maybe add a screenshot of your worksheet and identify the cells which you expect to find.

Comment: @FrancoisBotha If I merge A1:B1 & write "1" in the merged cell, the value of A1 would be 1, B1 would be empty. I need to get only one cell for all the merged cells.

Comment: I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code finds the cells `C21:C33`:

```
using (var wb = new XLWorkbook("test.xlsx"))
{
    var nr = wb.NamedRange("MyRange");
    foreach (var range in nr.Ranges)
    {
        var cellsToFind = range.Cells(c => c.MergedRange().FirstCell() == c);

        Console.WriteLine($"{cellsToFind.First().Address}:{cellsToFind.Last().Address}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, that a range which contains merged cells can contain multiple cells with values, e. g. whole column. The first code snippet would give me value for all cells, even for "invisible" merged cells, that would be otherwise null. But that would result in duplicated values, wouldn't it?

Comment: `MergedRange() ` returns null for hidden cells. Modified to `.Cells(c => c.MergedRange()!=null && c.MergedRange().FirstCell() == c)`.